# Can rejected edits show up in your notifications?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Recently, there was [a tab called "notifications"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) added to the global SE inbox. Can we add rejected edits to that tab as well? I have had many, many tag wiki edits rejected, but I didn't know about them, as I wasn't notified that they were rejected.

Comment: Can you not just follow up on your suggestions using the [activity:suggestions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167523/daviesgeek?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) tab? Not that I disagree with your proposal - I'd just hate to see the global inbox start collecting more and more notifications that may not be of interest to all.

Comment: I don't see how this suggestion is different from [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)... It's still a **notification**. The notifications got moved into that box. It's not a new feature request, it would just now be implemented differently if they decide to implement it at all.

Comment: @animuson That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!!

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Yes, but I'd like to see a notification, as it's more prominent and I don't have to go looking for it.

Comment: @animuson I changed my question to fit the new SuperCollider whatever thing.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta How could a rejected edit *not* be of interest to someone? It's hard to provide feedback otherwise, and people will just continue to do something wrong.

Comment: @slhck Absolutely!! I want feedback on my rejected edits as soon as possible.

Comment: @slhck, I'm about to make a slippery slope argument here, so feel free to ignore. But, that will tilt the bias of notifications strongly negative, for some users. So they'll ask, "why can't I see my *approved* suggestions too?" And down the slope we go...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I would say that you can see approved edits by your rep change. That's always how I see it...