# Notifications when users edit answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, edits, notifications

A few weeks ago I posted a question: Most Creative way to display 42. I received dozens of great answers. I loved reading them except I noticed one issue. People were editing their answers with new ways to answer the question, except I didn't receive any notifications and therefore didn't see any of their new answers. This a feature-request. When users make **substantial** edits to their answer, i.e. more than say 50 characters, the OP should get a notification about it.

Note: this can apply to all of Stack Exchange but I decided to post it here since its the most prevalent I think here.

I think substantial should mean 50+ characters added to the body.

If not a substantial edit, then perhaps the answerer should have the option to notify the OP of the edit, for example in a check box marked: "Notify OP of edit"

Comment: If this ever goes anywhere someone is going to ask for a definition of "substantial" that can be used to specify the code that will implement the feature...

Comment: I do not see how this is more prevalent here than anywhere else. I do like this idea.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a percentage? Otherwise you can replace a 40-character program by a completely different 40-character program and not have it be a "substantial" edit.

Comment: @marinus Although a percentage wouldn't accomplish much either. If I posted a long answer. 1000+ characters, and added 50 more characters, it wouldn't be considered substantial.

Comment: Starred questions show as with activity/updated when viewed from your profile. Do edits to answers count as activity?

Comment: I mean when viewed in the favorites tab of the profile, sorted by activity.

Comment: But you shouldn't have to favorite all of your own questions just in case someone edits an answer later.

Answer (score 1):

You can get updated on edits to a post using the [follow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/51) feature.