# Is it rude to answer a question and create a comment to point to the answer (OP > 1k rep)?

Tags: discussion

First and foremost, I'm not a big fan of calling someone out but I'm a bit unsure on this topic. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639947/bulider-design-pattern-to-make-generic-method-for-methods-having-large-number-of/30645203#30645203) a user answered a question and short after that created a comment under the question pointing to his answer and also pointing a user to the what to do when an answer fits the question page. Should this be considered rude, even taking into account that the OP already had 1k rep? Or is this all fine and dandy?

Furthermore I've the feeling that plenty of comments are made to somehow discredit other users answers or foster the own post and therefore increase likelihood of getting upvoted. Though, not sure on this one.

Comment: Not so rude as meaningless - OP get notified of new answers. If the answer author *edits* the answer then post a comment like "I've edited my answer, see now" then it's valid though since OP doesn't get notified of edits on answers.

Comment: Really? I thought OPs were notified for edits on answers.

Comment: I just flag these comments... there's no need for them and they strike me as trying to force the OP into looking at your answer ahead of someone else's

Comment: @ypercube yup, no notifications - and there's a [pending feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231204/notifications-when-users-edit-answers) asking to add such a feature. :)

Comment: After revisiting the linked page, the comments I was referring to are no longer available. Not sure if they got removed by a mod or if the user deleted them by himself. The OP also responded to the commenter that he already knew how to mark answers as solutions and therefore need no link on how to do that - but this comment is now also gone. I'm fine with comments on updates to notify the OP about the update (have done this in the past myself) - but I was referring to point to a post in the thread you have done short after you posted the answer without any updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not rude but it is extremely annoying, for both the OP and the visitors of that Q/A.

The OP gets annoyed by two messages in their inbox. One for the fact that their question was answered and one for the comment.

For the visitors such comment is nothing more then noise. They can see the answer, right? It is just down page. They'll get to it. And as most of those commentators don't bother to link their answer you would have to remember their username and then scroll. It is not helping anyone.

Nobody should leave such comments and when you see them, please flag them as *no longer needed* so a moderator can delete them.
We can only speculate why OP's leave such comments but one reasoning could be get drive more traffic and with that up votes to their answer. That might work but could have the adverse effect as well.

Some users might argue that you would leave a comment to inform the OP that the answer was updated. Such comments would only be appropriate if there was an initial comment under *the answer* that an issue needs to be addressed. In that case a comment that notifies that the requested changes have been made is advice-able so other parties can verify and then remove their comment.
Visitors of an answer can see by the following [*edited*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/257965/revisions) link under a post to see what was updated. You don't need a comment to get that idea. And this should never be done under the question anyway.

**tl;dr;** it is not rude but utter noise and those comments should be flagged as *no longer needed* so a moderator can remove them. When you find a persistent returning behavior of adding this noise, raise a custom moderator flag and explain the dubious acts of unhelpful comments. A moderator will then look into it and with enough cases might warn the user to adjust their commenting strategy.