# What is the "best way" to keep selected discussions on all meta sites synchronized?

Tags: support, notifications, meta, per-site-meta, translations

## Tl;Dr

There is an announcement about the new communication processes between international communities and Stack Exchange Inc. One of the processes is to keep the relevant posts on meta sites synchronized. The easy part is to translate the first revision of the posts but how we could keep the current revisions synced?

By "best way" I mean a method that could make the sync process work without applying brute force.

## Current situation

1. [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/289691) was created
2. The translations were made for es.so, ja.so, pt.so, ru.so and rus.se
3. A relevant revision was made to include some notes based on the answers

The Spanish translation doesn't include the notes added on the new revision, I didn't review the other translations yet.

Is there an "escalable way" to notify the "Spanish translation team" that there is a new revision that's worthy to translate?

### Current features

None of the currently available features tracks translations syncs.

#### Tags

A tag feed could be used to track activity on questions.

#### Chat Room

A tag feed could be added to a chat room.

#### Favorites

The members of the "Spanish translation team" could mark question as favorite

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/289691

> - The favorites tab on your profile has a counter indicating how many of your favorite questions have received answers since you last viewed that tab. When you click on the tab, recently changed questions will be highlighted. "Changed" includes comments on or edits to the question and new or edited answers. This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask.

Unfortunately the favorites questions comment/edit doesn't trigger a notification.

## Extract from From [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/289691)

> ## Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites
>
> > **TL;DR**
> >
> > - We need a channel for communication between the company and international communities as well as for international communities with one another. Currently, the best place for this is MSE.
> > - English will be used on MSE discussions and international sites will keep discussions in their own localized languages.
> > - Company initiatives will be shared in English on MSE and we will need the help of volunteer translators to post translated versions on their respective meta sites.
> > - Community initiatives will be shared on their respective meta site and will need to be translated for MSE. Then, they can spread across all other international metas as mentioned above.
> > - **We will keep discussions on all meta sites synchronized.**
> > - When a discussion on an international meta site is almost completed we need the volunteers’ help again to make a summary of what the international community said and post it as an answer on MSE.

## Related

- [Notifications when users edit answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231204/289691)
- [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343/289691)

Answer (score 3):

## Tl;Dr

So far, I think that we should made one or more feature requests. In the meantime, the timeline could be the source to be scrapped for hints of translations to be made.

## Description

The timeline for [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/289691) is https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/315311/timeline

Snapshot of the relevant edit made mentioned on the question

[image]

## Algorithm draft

1. Create a timeline link for the post that has to be synced
2. Periodically go to the timeline link and look to the items with the history label
3. Look at the expandable elements related to "edited" and check the changes made.
4. When something to be synced is found, go to the corresponding translations and add the translation of the new relevant content

NOTE:

Ask editors to include more descriptive edit summaries, maybe few keywords or some kind of versioning ([Semantic versioning](https://semver.org/)?)

## "Next"

<strike>Look if the timeline includes a RSS feed</strike>

### Watch

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/315311/timeline (question)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/315855/timeline (answer: [international](/questions/tagged/international) is a bad tag)

## Reference

- [Is there a feed for Stack Overflow that also has comments in RSS?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36738/289691)

Answer (score 2):

I've missed this revision. But thanks, I updated [SOru post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7847/15479).

About the question itself. Currently each tag has it's own RSS feed. But, AFAIK, only question/answer creations are tracked here.  It would be great, if SE team add special feed for revisions, so people (or even special chat) could subscribe on it. At least, it will solve informative issue.

Comment: I just found something that remembered me the post timeline page. See [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315799/289691) for details