# Opt out of moderator election notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications, election

Please add some way to opt out of moderator election notifications.

I don't have time to research who deserves my vote and therefore I will never vote.

Since I'm not taking part, I don't want election reminders to show up in my Stack Exchange inbox. They add up the more communities you take part in and almost every notification I've received in the last two months has been related to elections.

Comment: Be glad that we don't have compulsory voting ...

Comment: The idealism of hoping that everyone will vote on everything is terribly naive. I wish I could opt out of these notifications.

Comment: I have an account opened on nearly a 100 sites. Surely I shouldn't have to vote on a site which I left an answer 10 years ago and never visited since?

Comment: [Is there a way to not be notified of any elections ever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392960/is-there-a-way-to-not-be-notified-of-any-elections-ever) – I accidentally opened a dupe of this declined feature request. I feel the same way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We have a long list of things users would like to be able to ignore, and things that users would like to be notified of instead. But until we [develop some way to filter them out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294632) without just adding a bunch more processing for every single notification that has to go out, none of that is ever gonna happen. We're not interested in processing these preferences server-side.

Comment: It seems to me that not sending notifications to as many people would reduce processing resources, not increase them.

Comment: Unless the verification if a user should receive the notification adds significant resource usage...

Comment: I don't understand why a basically "sod off" answer gets so many upvotes and even gets accepted. If server-side computation resources were really the issue, then process them client-side. The link denies per-site preferences, but this could be a global preference.

Answer (score 4):

First off- by "opt out of moderator elections" I assume you mean the voting notifications. (As you don't get forced to run in an election). As already mentioned, there are a lot of notifications we want to filter out. Fortunately, by pressing the notification box on Stack Overflow or any other stackexchange site, the notifications are cleared. The election notifications are just like any other notification: Dismissable.

No notification requires you to press it, so if you don't want to vote, press the notification box and it goes away (notification box != the notification, it is the box you hover/press to see all notifications). You can ignore any and if you want all notifications you get.

But no, there is currently no notification filters and no way to block moderator election notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a bot up in the cloud to mark notifications you are not interested in as "read" before you see them. There is a lot that could be done in terms of customizations for notifications or otherwise with a bot. I could not find anything useful in my searches; the closest being a [chat bot](https://github.com/gchiu/rebolbot) that integrates with the StackOverflow chatrooms. Someone should start an open source Stack Exchange bot that would allow for various customizations.

Interestingly and semi relatedly, there has been a StackOverflow [bot user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4461216/joey-dorrani) before.

Comment: How can I mark just some notifications as read, without marking them all as read?